# Como pegar índice de um "for" avançado?

Tags: java, loop, for

Eu queria saber se consigo pegar algum tipo de variável de controle, de um `for` "avançado".

Por exemplo:

Em um for normal, eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < algumaCoisa.size() ou length; i++){
     //código..
}
```

essa variável `i` eu posso usar para percorrer os componentes, exemplo:

```
((JComponent) componentes.get(i)).requestFocus();
```

em um for avançado eu faria:

```
for(MeuComp comp: componentes){
//código..
}
```

Como eu faria pra pegar a posição que o `for` está e percorrer todos os componentes?

Obs: `MeuComp` é uma interface que contem métodos, que são implementados por componentes como `JTexefield`, `JComboBox` e etc. `componentes` é um `List` desses componentes, porém acredito que ia não seja tão importante, o exemplo pode ser em cima de qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não faz. O segundo exemplo é o que se chama *foreach* e sua função é pegar cada elemento de uma coleção de dados e usá-lo diretamente. Se deseja um índice use o `for` simples do primeiro exemplo, assim é possível percorrer todos os elementos e ter uma variável índice. Por isso existe ambos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Complementando o que o @Maniero falou, mesmo assim se você quiser pegar o índice, você pode fazer

```
int index = componentes.indexOf(comp);
```

Dessa maneira você obtêm o índice do seu elemento. Porém, se não me engano, é necessário que a sua classe `MeuComp` tenha `equals` e `hashCode` implementados

Comment: Obrigado a todos !

Comment: Como você sabe que `componentes` tem um `indexOf()`? Mesmo que tenha, sabe o custo disso?

Comment: Não sei, como o exemplo é simples, eu só dei uma dica pra caso ele precise. Nesse caso o custo não interessa, pois o conhecimento de que é possível vale mais.

Comment: @bigown pelo que entendi da pergunta(e pelo que já respondi desse OP), `componentes` é um `List`.

Comment: @Articuno Pode ser, mas não tem na pergunta, mas vendo que custo (exponencial, diga-se de passagem) não interessa dei aquela engolida seca.

Comment: @bigown não sei porque esse alarde todo, essa pergunta tá mais pra alguma atividade acadêmica ou algo do tipo. Se fosse pra alguma atividade que a performance realmente fosse importante, ele não estaria perguntando isso.

Comment: @MarcusDacorréggio é que na minha concepção o certo é sempre o certo e sempre desejável, ensinar o certo para quem está começando é o melhor a fazer. Acho uma pena que considere que ensinar de qualquer jeito seja o ideal.

Comment: @bigown em nenhum momento eu falei que aquilo era o ideal. Apenas mostrei pra ele que há possibilidade. Concordo com você, sempre devemos ensinar o certo. Porém, para reconhecermos o certo, também precisamos ter noção do errado, mesmo que não tão errado assim...

Comment: `Nesse caso o custo não interessa, pois o conhecimento de que é possível **vale mais**` E `essa pergunta tá mais pra alguma atividade acadêmica` isso deixa implícito que por ser acadêmico pode fazer de qualquer jeito, quando deveria ser o oposto, já que é um momento para se aprender o certo.

Comment: @bigown você que interpretou algo implícito, não tive intenção nenhuma. O ambiente acadêmico deve-se aprender o certo e o errado. Cada um com sua opinião, o importante é que ele teve sua resposta. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser uma alternativa funcional (Java 8+), também é possível sim. No site do Baeldung tem [vários exemplos](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-indices).

O que eu cheguei a usar foi o `protopack`. Então, vou focar nele.

A primeira coisa que se precisa é importar a dependência. Se estiver usando Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codepoetics</groupId>
    <artifactId>protonpack</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Ou então Gradle:

```
implementation com.codepoetics:protonpack:1.13
```

Ou, se não estiver usando gerenciador de pacotes, colocar o `jar` no `classpath` (escolha uma versão [aqui](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.codepoetics%22%20AND%20a%3A%22protonpack%22)).

Para usar o elemento com o seu índice, basta fazer o seguinte:

```java
Collection<T> myCollection;

    ...

Stream<Indexed<T>> collectionWithIndexes = StreamUtils
      .zipWithIndex(myCollection.stream());
```

Uma das vantagens com o `StreamUtils` é que você tem uma `Stream` do Java 8 para manipular. O objeto `Indexed<T>` tem 2 métodos de interesse: `getIndex()` e `getValue()`.

Você não descreveu como quer manipular os objetos, então posso fazer uma brincadeira qualquer aqui. Por exemplo, imprimir o índice e o `hashCode` dos elementos:

```java
StreamUtils.zipWithIndex(componentes)
  .map(indexedComp  -> indexedComp.getIndex() + ", hash " + indexedComp.getValue().hashCode())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```