# Problema em achar uma solução em um array / lista

Tags: java

Estou com um problema para conseguir imprimir dados de um array.

Eu tenho 2 classes (`Apartamento` e `Predio`).

Dentro da minha classe `Predio` eu tenho um método que adiciona o meu apartamento a um andar:

```
public void adicionarApto(int andar, Apartamento apto) {
    if (andar >= this.aptos.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("O prédio só tem " + this.aptos.length + " andares");
    }
    // encontra a primeira posição não preenchida
    int i = 0;
    while (i < this.aptos[andar].length && this.aptos[andar][i] != null)
        i++;
    if (i >= this.aptos[andar].length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Andar " + andar + " já está com todos os apartamentos cadastrados");
    }
    this.aptos[andar][i] = apto;
}
```

E não estou conseguindo pensar em como eu conseguiria criar uma list ou um array para poder extrair dados para poder imprimir

Classe `Apartamento`:

```
package model;

public class Apartamento {
    private Integer qtdQuarto, qtdBanheiro, qtdCozinha, qtdSala, numeroApt;

    public Apartamento() {
    }

    public Apartamento(Integer numeroApt) {
        this.numeroApt = numeroApt;
    }

    public Apartamento(Integer qtdQuarto, Integer qtdBanheiro, Integer qtdCozinha, Integer qtdSala, Integer numeroApt) {
        this.qtdQuarto = qtdQuarto;
        this.qtdBanheiro = qtdBanheiro;
        this.qtdCozinha = qtdCozinha;
        this.qtdSala = qtdSala;
        this.numeroApt = numeroApt;
    }

    public Integer getNumeroApt() {
        return numeroApt;
    }

    public void setNumeroApt(Integer numeroApt) {
        this.numeroApt = numeroApt;
    }

    public Integer getQtdQuarto() {
        return qtdQuarto;
    }

    public void setQtdQuarto(Integer qtdQuarto) {
        this.qtdQuarto = qtdQuarto;
    }

    public Integer getQtdBanheiro() {
        return qtdBanheiro;
    }

    public void setQtdBanheiro(Integer qtdBanheiro) {
        this.qtdBanheiro = qtdBanheiro;
    }

    public Integer getQtdCozinha() {
        return qtdCozinha;
    }

    public void setQtdCozinha(Integer qtdCozinha) {
        this.qtdCozinha = qtdCozinha;
    }

    public Integer getQtdSala() {
        return qtdSala;
    }

    public void setQtdSala(Integer qtdSala) {
        this.qtdSala = qtdSala;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Apartamento [qtdQuarto=" + qtdQuarto + ", qtdBanheiro=" + qtdBanheiro + ", qtdCozinha=" + qtdCozinha
                + ", qtdSala=" + qtdSala + "]";
    }


}
```

Classe `Predio`:

```
package model;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Predio {
    private String nome;

    private Apartamento[][] aptos;

    public Predio(int qtdAndares, int aptosPorAndar, String nome) {
        this.aptos = new Apartamento[qtdAndares][aptosPorAndar];
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void adicionarApto(int andar, Apartamento apto) {
        if (andar >= this.aptos.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O prédio só tem " + this.aptos.length + " andares");
        }
        // encontra a primeira posição não preenchida
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this.aptos[andar].length && this.aptos[andar][i] != null)
            i++;
        if (i >= this.aptos[andar].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Andar " + andar + " já está com todos os apartamentos cadastrados");
        }
        this.aptos[andar][i] = apto;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Apartamento[][] getAptos() {
        return aptos;
    }

    public void setAptos(Apartamento[][] aptos) {
        this.aptos = aptos;
    }

    public void imprimirDadosPredio() {

    }

}
```

E meu `main`:

```
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o nome do Predio: ");
        String nomePredio = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Andares do Predio: ");
        int qtdAndares = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Apartamentos por andar: ");
        int aptosPorAndar = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite o prefixo de numeração dos Apartamentos: ");
        int prefApt = scanner.nextInt();

        Predio predio = new Predio(qtdAndares, aptosPorAndar,nomePredio);

        Apartamento apartamento = new Apartamento();

        for (int andar = 0; andar < qtdAndares; andar++) {
            for (int apto = 0; apto < aptosPorAndar; apto++) {
                int numero = andar * prefApt + apto;
                System.out.println("Digite a qtd de Quartos do apartamento "+numero+": ");
                int qtdQuartos = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Digite a qtd de Banheiros do apartamento "+numero+": ");
                int qtdBanheiros = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Digite a qtd de Cozinhas do apartamento "+numero+": ");
                int qtdCozinha = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Digite a qtd de Salas do apartamento "+numero+": ");
                int qtdSala = scanner.nextInt();

                predio.adicionarApto(andar, new Apartamento(qtdQuartos,qtdBanheiros,qtdCozinha,qtdSala,numero));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

No meu `main` eu crio o meu prédio, seto o nome dele e alguns parâmetros como: `qtdAndares`, `aptosPorAndar`.

E no construtor de minha classe `Predio` (eu tenho uma composição, tenho um array bidimensional de apt em minha classe `Predio`):

```
public Predio(int qtdAndares, int aptosPorAndar, String nome) {
    this.aptos = new Apartamento[qtdAndares][aptosPorAndar];
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

E depois eu utilizo um `for` para adicionar o meu apartamento ao meu índice (Andar), com todas informações de apartamento, mas depois disso eu estou com um problema em como criar uma lista ou como passar um array como parâmetro para um método que eu irei fazer para imprimir os dados, pois no meu `main` eu só tenho um objeto e não um array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer imprimir os dados dos apartamentos do prédio, pode fazer isso diretamente no `main`, já que a classe `Predio` possui um *getter* para obter os apartamentos:

```
// dentro do main
for (Apartamento[] andar : predio.getAptos()) {
    for (Apartamento apto : andar) {
        System.out.println("Apto " + apto.getNumeroApt() + " tem " + apto.getQtdBanheiro() + " banheiro(s)");
        // imprima os dados do apto da maneira que achar melhor
    }
}
```

Evidentemente, `predio.getAptos()` (ou o próprio `predio`) poderia ser passado para outro método (possivelmente de outra classe que sabe como imprimir), e este método faria o `for` da mesma maneira:

```
public class OutraClasseQueSabeImprimirAptos {
    public void imprime(Predio predio) {
        for (Apartamento[] andar : predio.getAptos()) {
            for (Apartamento apto : andar) {
                System.out.println("Apto " + apto.getNumeroApt() + " tem " + apto.getQtdBanheiro() + " banheiro(s)");
                // imprima os dados do apto da maneira que achar melhor
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

E no `main` você chamaria este método, passando o prédio como parâmetro.

---

#### *getters* e *setters*

Não é algo diretamente relacionado ao problema, mas a classe `Apartamento` tem *setters* que talvez não façam sentido. Uma vez criado um apartamento, a quantidade de quartos, cozinhas e banheiros pode mudar? *Talvez* possa, se o morador puder quebrar paredes e fazer reformas, mas de qualquer forma, não parece fazer muito sentido ter um *setter* para esses dados.

O mesmo vale para a classe `Predio`. Uma vez criado um prédio, ele pode mudar de nome? (talvez, então `setNome` pode até fazer sentido, dependendo do contexto e dos requisitos do sistema). Mas ele pode mudar a quantidade de andares e apartamentos? Talvez o método `setAptos` não faça tanto sentido assim.

Isso é só para te fazer pensar um pouco e não sair criando *getters* e *setters* para tudo automaticamente. Só crie o que fizer sentido. Leia mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=getter+setter+encapsulamento).

---

Outro detalhe é que na classe `Apartamento` o número é guardado no campo `numeroApt`. Mas se ele faz parte de um apartamento, é meio "óbvio" que ele se refere ao número do apartamento, então ele poderia se chamar apenas `numero`.

Comment: Eu acho que a correta é a terceira. Claro, sempre é possível definir o problema de uma forma que as primeiras opções sejam corretas, mas em quase todos os casos reais, e não apenas um exercício não será correto. E se vai exercitar então seria melhor fazer do jeito correto para o caso real porque exercitar o errado ajuda acostumar fazer o errado. Um objeto não deveria saber onde será impresso algo, não importa pra ele se é console, GUI , web, API, etc. A classe tem mais de uma responsabilidade e não é coesa quando manda imprimir algo dela mesma. Não é o fim do mundo mas é errado.

Comment: Eu acho curioso que as pessoas querem programar orientado a objeto que trouxe muito mais confusão que o procedural, antes você não tinha que pensar sobre isto, agora tem, e aí tem gente que sempre vai questionar se deveria fazer assim, porque ter a impressão separada para alguns não é OOP, para outros não é SOLID ou pelo menos o SRP, ambos ferem alguns princípios que só acontecem por usar OOP. Se vai fazer OOP então faz certo.

Comment: @Maniero Tem razão, removi as outras opções da resposta...

Comment: Até são opções, só não acho que são as primárias, é aquela coisa, se está fazendo algo simples só pra fazer funcionar e o *design* não é importante então ok, é que eu acho estranho as pessoas usarem uma linguagem que se vende como OOP (agora pararam um pouco mas adoravam falar que ela era só OOP) e não fazer seguindo preceitos de bom *design*, ainda que eles possam ser questionados em algo simples. Sem falar que algumas pessoas dizem que colocar tudo junto ao objeto é bom OOP (eu acho que não é, e muita gente também).

Comment: Opa vlw pessoal, uma dúvida: esse meu metodo que adiciona o apartamento ao andar na classe predio eu estaria colocando um "dever que não é da classe predio" ou eu estou enganado? No caso teria que esse metodo em um controller? Hehe eu tou pensando em como tirar esse metodo dessa classe, mas estou me confundindo um pouco.

Comment: @hkotsubo e vlw pela atenção !!

Comment: @JoaoSpirit Nesse caso acho um exagero colocar o método `adicionarApto` em outra classe, já que um prédio "sabe" como se organizam os seus andares e os aptos de cada andar.

Comment: @hkotsubo opa mano você poderia me tirar apenas uma dúvida? Já tentei de todas maneira em pegar o valor atual do meu indice (Andar), para imprimir ex:         for (Apartamento[] andar : predio.getAptos()) {
            for (Apartamento apto : andar) {
                System.out.println("Apto " + apto.getNumeroApt() +" tem " + apto.getQtdBanheiro() + " banheiro(s)"+ apto.getQtdCozinha() + " cozinha(s)"+ apto.getQtdQuarto() + " quarto(s)"+ apto.getQtdSala() + " sala(s)");
                // imprima os dados do apto da maneira que achar melhor
            }
        }

Comment: @JoaoSpirit Usando essa sintaxe do for não dá pra pegar o índice, só dá fazendo o for tradicional: veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224406/112052) - se bem que também daria pra pegar o andar dividindo o número do apto por 100 (mas acho mais fácil fazer o for normal mesmo)